# Changing the size of an ImageView when image clicked

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am trying to get a picture, within an ImageView, to increase in size when clicked. I have searched for a number of days, but have not found exactly what I need.
At the moment I am using the TouchImageView from MikeOrtiz, and it works in that, when the image is clicked, it zooms in. 
But I want the image to increase in size, not just to zoom in, and while leaving the rest of the page opaque, the image needs to increase to the size of the screen while retaining its aspect ratio, i.e. it is a square image, so it should not become a rectangular image.

I have the following XML code:

```
<LinearLayout
<com.example.TouchImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/CompanyHeader" 
    android:src="@drawable/entrancex250"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am using the TouchImageView from:

https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java

As explained, what this does is to zoom in, but what I need is to make the image itself bigger when clicked, and then back to its normal size when clicked again.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   public class TheCompany extends Activity implements OnMenuItemClickListener{

        public static final float screen_width;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.the_company);
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            screen_width = metrics.widthPixels;

        }

    }
```

Then in your page do this :

```
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                float scale =  TheCompany.screen_width / view.getWidth();
                if(view.getScaleX() == 1) {
                    view.setScaleY(scale);
                    view.setScaleX(scale);
                }else{
                    view.setScaleY(1);
                    view.setScaleX(1);
                }
            }


        });
```

Comment: Thank @micnubinub, where would I put this code? I have a class that calls the XML that holds code put above.

Comment: Thank you! I am quite new at this, so apologies for the possibly silly question, but do I just put the above code in the Java class that renders the XML layout? I have done just that and I get errors. It says for example:  ImageView cannot be resolved 
  to a type.

Comment: It also fails saying MotionEvent cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: I want the image that is currently a small square, with text just below it, to be enlarged when the user taps on it ...

Comment: enlarged by how much?

Comment: That while it remains as a square image, it occupies the width of the screen, so it will depend on the screen size. So at the moment, the image is within a small square, it occupies about 1/3 of the screen, in andscape mode. Under the image there is text. I want to have the possibility of the image coming out of the square and occupying the width of the screen... Please let me know if I have not explained well enough. I can try and get a picture to explain it better.

Comment: it crashes when I try to go to the "page" that has the picture I want to click. I tried to post the LogCat here, but it is too long. It is Caused by a Null Pointer Exception in the line:           getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

Comment: Move the first three lines to the activity that you're opening the 'page' in paste the lines under setContentView:

Comment: Thank you for all your help. It still crashes ... now it complains, still with NPE, but this time on the line:     imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but the Java class where this code is is declared as follows: public class TheCompany extends Activity implements OnMenuItemClickListener Does this affect it?

Comment: hopefully that takes care of things

Comment: I put the code as you sai, and I get the following error when I saved the class: The blank final field screen_width may not have been initialized

Comment: Would it help if I gave you the complete java class that renders my company? I can't do this in this comments...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55067/discussion-between-user3079872-and-micnubinub).

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is to increase the size of the ImageView, then you should not use TouchImageView at all, but ImageView instead.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/picture" 
    android:clickable="true" />
```

and in your java class setonclicklistener on this imageview and inside onclick change the size of the imageview by setting layout params.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(newWidth, newHeight);
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Here newWidth and newHeight are the dimensions to which to which you want set the imageview on click.

Comment: Thank you Nitesh. Do I just put the java code above in my class that renders the XML?

Comment: At the moment the java class is:public class TheCompany extends Activity implements OnMenuItemClickListener

Comment: @user3079872 If this answer helped you, kindly select this answer and up vote it so that it can help others as well.

Comment: @NiteshKhatri  doing smae animation using scale in xml but want this type of aniamtion http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2qx2if how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this great library : [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)

It supports zooming and have a tap listener, so you just have to zoom on tap

Comment: Thanks Plumillon. Using TouchImageView works and it zooms, but I want the image to increase in size within the current view. Would this code do that?

Comment: If you mean take all the place the parent View is offering when you zoom in, yes

Answer (score 0):

an alternative can be to use the following code

```
TouchImageView v = (TouchImageView) getActivity().findViewById("imageView2");
v.setHeight(fill_parent);
v.setWidth(fill_parent);
```

Comment: Thank you rijul. Do I just put this code in the java class that calls the xml that holds the above XML code? I have just done that, and I get errors, for example: The method getActivity() is undefined for the type TheCompany --> this is the error for the first line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to put down what I actually ended up doing thanks to @micnubinub. I put his answer as the correct one as they helped me get to where I needed to be. But the actual code is not in the answer, so I thought to put it here, in case it helps anyone else.

First of all @micnubinub suggested I used dialog to show the image when it gets clicked. So I created a dialog.xml under res/layout as follows:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minHeight="910dp"
android:minWidth="910dp"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Then the Java class that would show the image when clicked is as follows:

```
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(TheCompany.this, R.style.CustomDialog);
    if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & 
            Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 
                Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
            // on a large screen device ...
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_xlarge);}

        else dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);


    ImageView im = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    im.setImageResource(R.drawable.entrancex250);
    im.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    dialog.dismiss();
    }
    });
    dialog.show();
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }
    }); 
}
```

I also created a customdialog in Styles as follows:

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/zoom_in</item>
<item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/zoom_out</item>
</style>
```

This worked really well, thanks again @micnubinub.

The dialog_xlarge is the same as dialog, except with larger height and width.